# HTML input values clearing upon adding warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have code that will add a input field when a button is clicked. I have it set to display a bootstrap warning when the limit == 5 (counter). It is done all by setting .innerhtml My issue is that when I hit add field after 5 (the limit) times it adds in the warning but it clears out the field values. How can I rework this code so that the values do not disappear? I have spent the past 2 hours on Google and no luck trying different things, hopefully you guys can help here.

```js
function typePicker(){
 var sel=document.getElementById("type");
 var typeInputs=document.getElementById("typeInputs");
 var aps = '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="ipaddress" id="ipaddress" placeholder="IP Address"></div><!-- IP Address --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mac-address" id="mac-address" placeholder="MAC Address"></div><!-- MAC Address --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="range" id="range" placeholder="Range in M"></div><!-- Range --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="textbox-n form-control" name="bands" id="bands" placeholder="Bands" ></div><!-- Bands --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="channels" id="channels" placeholder="Channel(s)"></div><!-- Channels --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"><label for="">PoE</label><br><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option1"> Yes</label><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option2"> No</label></div>  <br><br><!-- PoE --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate"></div><!-- Warranty Date --><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control"  id="location" placeholder="Location"></div><!-- Location --></div>';
 var cables = '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="type" name="type" placeholder="Type"></div><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost"></div><!-- Cost --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity"></div><!-- Quantity --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location"></div><!-- Location -->';
 var deskPhones = '<div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost"></div><!-- Cost --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location"></div><!-- Location --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number"></div> <!-- Phone Number --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="extension" name="extension" placeholder="Extension"></div><!-- Extension -->';
 var desktops = '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpu" name="cpu" placeholder="CPU"></div><!-- CPU --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="ram" name="ram" placeholder="RAM"></div> <!-- RAM --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="gpu" name="gpu" placeholder="GPU"></div><!-- GPU --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vram" name="vram" placeholder="VRAM"></div><!-- VRAM --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="numDrive" name="numDrive" placeholder="Number of Drives"></div><!-- Number of Drives --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="sizeDrive name="sizeDrive" placeholder="Size of Drive(s)"></div><!-- Size of Drive(s) --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="sizeDrive" name="sizeDrive" placeholder="Type of Drive(s)"></div><!-- Type of Drives --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost"></div><!-- Cost --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="life" name="life" placeholder="Life Expectancy In Months" min="0.25" step="0.25"></div><!-- Expected Life in Months --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="usbPorts" name="usbPorts" placeholder="Number of USB Ports"></div><!-- Number of USB Ports --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Machine Name"></div><!-- Machine Name --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate"></div><!-- Warranty Date --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location"></div><!-- Location --><div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"><label for="">Stand Alone</label><br><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="standAlone" id="option1"> Yes</label><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="standAlone" id="option2"> No</label></div>  <br><br><!-- Stand Alone -->';
 var laptops = '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control"  id="cpu" name="cpu" placeholder="CPU"></div><!-- CPU --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="ram" name="ram" placeholder="RAM"></div><!-- RAM --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="gpu" name="gpu" placeholder="GPU"></div><!-- GPU --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vram" name="vram" placeholder="VRAM"></div><!-- VRAM --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="sizeDrive" name="sizeDrive" placeholder="Size of Drive(s)"></div><!-- Size of Drive(s) --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="typeDrive"name="typeDrive" placeholder="Type of Drive(s)"></div><!-- Type of Drives --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost"></div><!-- Cost --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="life" name="life" placeholder="Life Expectancy In Months" min="0.25" step="0.25"></div><!-- Expected Life in Months --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="usbPorts" name="usbPorts" placeholder="Number of USB Ports"></div><!-- Number of USB Ports --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Machine Name"></div><!-- Machine Name --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate"></div><!-- Warranty Date --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location"></div><!-- Location --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" name="user" placeholder="User"></div><!-- User --><div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"><label for="">Stand Alone</label><br><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="standAlone" id="option1"> Yes</label><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="standAlone" id="option2"> No</label></div>  <br><br><!-- Stand Alone -->';
 var mobilePhones = '<div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost"></div><!-- Cost --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="lifeExpectancy" name="lifeExpectancy" placeholder="Life Expectancy"></div><!-- Life Expectancy --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate"></div><!-- Warranty Date --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number"></div><!-- Phone Number --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="os" name="os" placeholder="Operating System"></div><!-- OS --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="simNumber" name="simNumber" placeholder="SIM Number"></div><!-- SIM Number -->';
 var monitors = '<div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cost" nameid="cost" placeholder="Cost"></div><!-- Cost --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="life" name="life" placeholder="Life Expectancy In Months" min="0.25" step="0.25"></div><!-- Expected Life in Months --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate"></div><!-- Warranty Date --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location"></div><!-- Location --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="resolution" name="resolution" placeholder="Resolution"></div><!-- Resolution --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="panelType" name="panelType" placeholder="Panel Type"></div><!-- Panel Type -->';
 var printers = '<div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost"></div><!-- Cost --><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="lifeExpectancy" name="lifeExpectancy" placeholder="Life Expectancy"></div><!-- Life Expectancy --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate"></div><!-- Warranty Date --><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control"  id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location"></div><!-- Location -->                        ';
 var projectors = '<div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate"></div><!-- Warranty Date --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location"></div><!-- Location --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="resolution" name="resolution" placeholder="Resolution"></div><!-- Resolution -->';
 var routers = '<div class="form-group "><select class="custom-select form-control" id="sel-speed" name="router-speed" onchange="speed()"><option selected>Select Router Speed</option><option value="100">10/100 Mbps</option><option value="1000">10/100/1000 Mbps</option><option value="10000">10/100/1000/10000 Mbps</option><option value="other">Other</option></select></div><!-- Router Speed --><div class="form-group" id="speed" name="speed"></div> <!-- Router Speed other input only show when above "other" is selected --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="life" name="life" placeholder="Life Expectancy In Months" min="0.25" step="0.25"></div><!-- Expected Life in Months --><div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"><label for="">PoE</label><br><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option1"> Yes</label><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option2"> No</label></div><br><br><!-- PoE --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate"></div><!-- Warranty Date -->';
 var switches = '<div class="form-group "><select class="custom-select form-control" id="sel-speed" name="switch-speed" onchange="speed()"><option selected>Select Switch Speed</option><option value="100">10/100 Mbps</option><option value="1000">10/100/1000 Mbps</option><option value="10000">10/100/1000/10000 Mbps</option><option value="other">Other</option></select></div><!-- Switch Speed --><div class="form-group" id="speed"></div> <!-- Switch Speed other input only show when above "other" is selected --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="life" name="life" placeholder="Life Expectancy In Months" min="0.25" step="0.25"></div><!-- Expected Life in Months --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="switch-ports" name="switch-ports" placeholder="Number of Ports" min="1"></div><!-- Number of Ports --><div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"><label for="">PoE</label><br><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option1"> Yes</label><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="poe" id="option2"> No</label></div><br><br><!-- PoE --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate"></div><!-- Warranty Date -->';
 var tablets = '<div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Date Bought" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="date-bought" name="dateBought"></div><!-- Date Bought --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost"></div><!-- Cost --><div class="form-group"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="life" name="life" placeholder="Life Expectancy In Months" min="0.25" step="0.25"></div><!-- Expected Life in Months --><div class="form-group"><input placeholder="Warranty Expiration Date" class="textbox-n form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type="date")" onblur="(this.type="text")" id="warranty-date" name="warrantyDate"></div><!-- Warranty Date --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location"></div>            <!-- Location --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="ram" name="ram" placeholder="RAM"></div><!-- RAM --><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="resolution" name="resolution" placeholder="Resolution"></div><!-- Resolution -->';
 // var other = '<div class="form-group"><label for="customField" class="control-label">Custom Field</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="customField" name="customField" placeholder="Custom Field"></div>';
 var other = '<div class="form-group"><label for="customField" class="control-label">Custom Field</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="customField" name="customField" placeholder="Custom Field"> </div> <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary add" id="add" value="Add Field"/>'; 
 var type = '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="type" name="type" placeholder="Asset Type"></div>';

if(sel.value=="aps"){
 typeInputs.innerHTML=aps;
}

if(sel.value=="cables"){
  typeInputs.innerHTML=cables;
}

if(sel.value=="deskPhones"){
  typeInputs.innerHTML=deskPhones;
}

if(sel.value=="desktops"){
  typeInputs.innerHTML=desktops;
}

if(sel.value=="laptops"){
 typeInputs.innerHTML=laptops;
}

if(sel.value=="mobilePhones"){
 typeInputs.innerHTML=mobilePhones;
}

if(sel.value=="monitors"){
 typeInputs.innerHTML=monitors;
}

if(sel.value=="printers"){
 typeInputs.innerHTML=printers;
}

if(sel.value=="projectors"){
 typeInputs.innerHTML=projectors;
}

if(sel.value=="routers"){
 typeInputs.innerHTML=routers;
}

if(sel.value=="switches"){
 typeInputs.innerHTML=switches;
}

if(sel.value=="tablets"){
 typeInputs.innerHTML=tablets;
}

if(sel.value=="other"){
 typeInputs.innerHTML=type + other;
}


}

var typeInputs=document.getElementById("typeInputs");
var otherMessage = '<br><br><div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Limit of 5 custom fields for your plan!</div>';
var sel=document.getElementById("type");
var limit = 6;
var counter = 1;
$(document).on("click",".add",function(){
 if(counter < limit){
  if(sel.value !="other"){
   counter = 1;
  }
  counter ++;
  if(counter == limit){
   var p = document.getElementById("typeInputs").innerHTML;
   return typeInputs.innerHTML = p  + otherMessage;
  }
  var n= $(this).prev(".form-group" ).length+1;
 var temp = $(this).prev(".form-group" ).clone();
 $('input:first',temp).attr('placeholder','Custom Field').val("");
 $(this).prev( ".form-group" ).after(temp);
 }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="type" class="control-label">Type</label>
     <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Type of Asset" name="type" data-live-search="true" id="type" onchange="typePicker()">
      <option value="aps">Access Point</option>
      <option value="cables">Cable</option>
    
      <option value="other">Other</option>
     </select>
    </div>
                                
    <div class="form-group" id="typeInputs">
                                    
    </div>
    
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have removed some of the options in the select to condense the code for here. I have also not included the typePicker function because it just displays the html based off the select value. I can edit to include this if it is needed. Stack Overflow says it is too much code not enough content if I add that right now.

Comment: Could you replicate your code here on snippet or [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsn9gq8q/)?

Comment: @divy3993 I have gone ahead and added a snippet at your request. One thing I noticed while testing that snippet to make sure it is the same as my issue I noticed it was not just the custom fields that values reset but also the asset type one that is a text input.

Comment: Instead of just displaying the message, you're resetting your input with this line `typeInputs.innerHTML = p  + otherMessage;`

Comment: @FluffyKitten I knwo that line is resetting it but how else can I do it so it doesn't reset? Is snapjs's method one you would recommend?

Comment: If you knew that line was resetting it, then you need to include that in your question! We're not mind readers - we don't know what you already know, what you have tried, or exactly what you need help with if you don't tell us :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten I thought I knew, I guess I phrased that wrong, I was almost sure because it started happening after I added that but thought it might also have been the getting ID part.

Comment: You still need to give us all the relevant information to help us help you. If adding that line was what triggered the problem, then tell us. It might not be the cause, but it gives us a starting point. The more relevant info and less unrelated info you can give us, it easier it is for us to help. For example, in your snippet its not clear that we have to choose "other" to find the problem. If we have to spend time blindly working out your code and how it works, that will put some people off helping. I'm not reprimanding you, just advising how to help us help you for future questions :)

Comment: "*Is snapjs's method one you would recommend?*" - What do you think? Does it make sense to you? There are a number of ways to do this, and its not the way I would have suggested (for example it will be more complicated to remove the message again), but it is an acceptable way of doing it, and if it suits your specific needs then that's what matters.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Okay thank you for the advice, will make sure to write a better question next time. I do see what you mean by I didn't give enough detail on the exact issue.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Reason I asked is maybe there was a better way that is more adaptable for future use. His does work now I tried it, I do not see what you mean by it will be harder to remove the message later. Why would it be harder? Could you not just make `.innerHTML='" `   ?

Comment: Again, it depends on what you need. There is no single solution that is "best" in every situation. If you just need to clear the contents again, then setting the innerHTML is fine, but if you wanted to remove the `warning` element that you added its more complicated - you might want to do this if you had applied CSS styling to the div for example.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Oh okay thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely here

```
var p = document.getElementById("typeInputs").innerHTML;
return typeInputs.innerHTML = p  + otherMessage;
```

The `innerHTML` attribute is not reflecting the updated inputs.  Instead of setting `innerHTML` to itself plush a message string, perhaps try creating an element and appending it to the DOM object.

```
var warning = document.createElement('div');
warning.innerHTML = '<br><br><div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Limit of 5 custom fields for your plan!</div>';
document.getElementById("typeInputs").appendChild(warning);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, I am not sure why I didn't think of it. I guess I was just thinking they are together and need to be grouped. Hopefully next time I will remember not everything has to be grouped nice as I like it.